# switch value with div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a div with value like a button then input it to submit value the code look like this.

```
    <div id="btn" name="Dragon" style="width:20px; height:20px; border:1px solid black;"></div>

    <input type="submit" id="submita" value="">

    <script>

    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

    btn.addEventListener('click', function( event ){ 

document.getElementById("submita").value = event.target.name;}, false);

}

    </script>
```

the code take a value from div's name atribut then input it to submit value. if it with button element it work but div doesn't work.

how to this?

Comment: Suggest you use jQuery (as you tagged the question jQuery too). Your code will be simpler. Are you happy to have a jQuery answer?

Comment: i'm still in process learn. so i'm stills not understand JQuery too much. i'm preferrer Javascript. thank you.

Comment: OK pure Javascript Answer below.

Comment: You have a redundant } at the end of the script container.

Comment: @Vladislav Qulin: Already noted in answer. Well spotted though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `getAttribute()` DOM method as `name` is not a property of a `div`:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/JM9nH/9/

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    document.getElementById("submita").value = event.target.getAttribute("name");
}, false);
```

Note: Your example code also has an extra closing `}` at the end which I removed.

Comment: sory, i'm still can't to give reputation others but thank you hehe

Answer (score 2):

Use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) in jquery to get the name of div

```
 $("#btn").click(function () {

    $("#submita").val($(this).attr("name"));
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JM9nH/8/)

Comment: your code it's working but can you convet it to javascript? thank you

Comment: sory, i'm still can't to give a reputation to others but thank you hehe